# Using UIButton Text as Text Input - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Hello I have a profilelbl variable as below which is a uibutton. I want the text of the button to be an input in my database (parse). But I couldn't figured it out. I tried lots of things but still getting error:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var profileLbl: UIButton!

  var notification = PFObject(className: "notifications")

        notification["actionReceiverName"] = profilelbl.text /*not working*/

     /*    also tried

   notification["actionReceiverName"] = sender.profilelbl.text

   notification["actionReceiverName"] = profilelbl.title    */
```

Comment: profilelbl.titleLabel.text didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it easy like that

```
if let button = profilelbl as? UIButton {
    if let title = button.titleForState(.Normal) {
        println(title)
        notification["actionReceiverName"] = title
    }
}
```

Comment: glad it worked, (just be sure if your button state is Normal for this script)

Answer (score 0):

Using UI objects to save/load data is a very bad idea. Using user-visible strings programmatically is an even worse idea. @ÖzgürErsil answered the question you asked, but the better answer to your question is "Don't do that. Ever."

Here are 2 examples where your approach will fail:

1. If 6 months later you want to change your UI and rename your button,
   you won't remember that the button title is used in code and your
   code will break. To that you would have to alter your database to
   use a different string value.
2. If you decide to localize your app for foreign
   languages, the button titles will come up in the local language, and
   your code will break. There is no clean way to fix this problem,
   since each local language would use a different version of the
   button title.

It would be better to put unique tag numbers on your buttons, then look up text strings using the tags and pass those strings to your database.

Say you have button tags starting at 100.

You'd use code like this:

```
let buttonStrings = ["button1", "button2", "button3"]
let baseButtonTag = 100;

@IBAction func handleButton(sender: UIButton)
{
  let tag = sender.tag
  if tag >= baseButtonTag && tag < baseButtonTag + buttonStrings.count
  {
    let index = sender.tag - baseButtonTag
    let buttonString = buttonStrings[index];
    //Now use buttonString with your database as desired.
  }
}
```